# How to add slowmotion effect in libgdx>

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I want to add slow motion effect with a collision as a trigger. So I want to have an effective way to trigger a slowmotion effect on bodies as well as sprites that can be caled in the update method. Can anyone please help me with this or provide a link as to where I can find the answer?

Comment: For the entire scene: Simply slow down frame time. If you feed movement and physics calculation with a frame time (typically 0.0167 s @ 60 fps), feed the entire thing with a smaller value, eg. one tenth of it. This causes any displacement of things to be smaller -> appear to be slower. Time in a game need not be in sync with real-world time. If you only want part of the scene in slowmotion, you must have separate separate displacement calculation, with slower time, for that part.